# Error while communicating to web service - Error reading XMLStreamReader

Tags: web-services, mule, mule-component

I find below error when I try to consume a webservice from Mule ESB 3.8.0. I am using the Web Service Consumer and I get the below error

What happens here is, I am able to consume the webservice using SOAP UI tool. Can anyone suggest?

My mule config is as below:

```
   <flow name="ws-testFlow">
      <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="aaa-testws"
            connector-ref="com.srk.esb.cbs.jmsConnector" doc:name="cbs.offramp.inbox" />
            
       <logger level="INFO" category="com.srk.esb.cbsinterface"
                    message="Test WS Payload #[payload]" doc:name="Logger" />
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="PublishMessage" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
                    
                    <!-- <logger level="INFO" category="com.srk.esb.cbsinterface"
                    message="Test Response WS Payload #[payload]" doc:name="Logger" />
                    
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/> -->
                    
    </flow>
```

**Error:**

```
2022-03-03 22:23:52,674 [WARN] phase.PhaseInterceptorChain |  | # |  | **Interceptor for {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
 org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader.**
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:259) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:65) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:849) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.sendResultBackToCxf(MuleUniversalConduit.java:323) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:286) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:193) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481) ~[cxf-api-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:293) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:131) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.processNext(WSConsumer.java:186) ~[mule-module-ws-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.process(WSConsumer.java:110) ~[mule-module-ws-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:123) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:208) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:201) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:200) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:53) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286) ~[mule-core-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
**Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'R' (code 82) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]**
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:647) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2054) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1131) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1154) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at org.mule.module.xml.stax.DelegateXMLStreamReader.nextTag(DelegateXMLStreamReader.java:238) ~[mule-module-xml-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.mule.module.xml.stax.DelegateXMLStreamReader.nextTag(DelegateXMLStreamReader.java:238) ~[mule-module-xml-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:161) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    ... 82 more
2022-03-03 22:23:52,695 [ERROR] exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy |  | # |  | 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Error reading XMLStreamReader..
Payload               : {NullPayload}
Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element               : null @ test-interface:null:null
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException: Error reading XMLStreamReader..**
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.processNext(WSConsumer.java:199)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.process(WSConsumer.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:123)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:208)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:201)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:200)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the stacktrace of the error we can find the real issue:

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'R' (code 82) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
```

This means that the response from the SOAP WebService is not an XML, because it doesn't start with a '<' character but with an 'R'.

The cause for this is unclear and there is not enough information in the question to do a deeper analysis. However I will suggest the more common causes:

1. There is some error in the server so it is returning an error message. That indicates some difference in the request. See below point.
2. The request is not constructed in the Web Service Consumer to match exactly what SOAP UI sends. Mule Web Service Consumer constructs the request from scratch using a SOAP library. You can check what SOAP UI is sending using Code / HTTP Request and you can compare with the Mule request using the [HTTP Wire logging](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging) feature.
3. The service is not even SOAP and is not expected to return a valid SOAP response nor XML. It is not returning JSON either (inferred from the response starting with 'R'). I believe it is unlikely because you are using SOAP UI but you didn't share any details. The WSC only supports SOAP Web Services so the response has to be a SOAP XML.

Comment: Thanks aled. In the mean time I actually wrote a CXF adapter code and tried using it. I found that I am able to communicate now with the custom CXF adapter I write. But I am curious to know if the web service is written using CXF, then Web Consumer adapter on mule wouldnt work?

Comment: The Web Service Consumer in Mule 3 is built on CXF, but depending on how you are using it may not be sending exactly the same request that SOAP UI or the CXF code you mentioned. Try looking into the HTTP request each of these methods actually send and compare.

Comment: Not related to the issue, Mule 3.8.0 is quite old and it includes an old version of CXF. Mule 4.4.0 is the latest release at this time.

Comment: True. But we are adhering to client's requirement. Also CXF in 3.9 is not an out of box solution. So I am going ahead with the custom adapter. Thanks Aled for the support